# Upgrade of windows 8.1 to higher version without data lose on the C:\ drive

Tags: windows-8.1, upgrade

I have a lot of pdf files on different places in my C:\ drive with links to my D:\ drive where the files are saved. It will be unreasonably difficult to create them from scratch on the various places where they currently are.

I would like to know, with highest possible certainty, if in the future, when windows 8.1 will cease to be supported (as it is the case of Windows XP now) it will (and how) possible to upgrade to the new version of windows, whatever the number or version of Windows will be??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless your hard disk has severe problems, upgrading from any version of Windows to another is pretty safe

Comment: Please How is called the program I use to upgrade to a higher version of Win 8.1?

Comment: Usually through this site https://support.microsoft.com/en-nz/help/4009470/windows-8-1-windows-server-2012-r2-update-history, you'd find the latest update to win8.1, if you want to upgrade to Win10, uou'll need the ISO.

Answer (score 0):

Mainstream support for Windows 8.1 ended on January 9, 2018. This means that Microsoft is no longer providing design updates, non-security updates, or phone/online support. None of these are a huge deal.

Extended support will continue until January 10, 2023. Once the extended support period is past, they will no longer provide any support for any bugs, security updates, etc.

You could have upgraded to Windows 10 for free, but I believe that period has now passed. You could still try using the [Windows 10 installation media](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10).

It's always recommended to backup your data to an external source before upgrading. There's always that chance that you could lose the data. You could choose to back it up to an external hard drive, or back it up to a cloud based service like Google Drive if you don't have too much to back up.

With how important the data sounds, it would be wise to always have a backup of the PDF files and any other important data.

Comment: The free upgrade still works. The difference is that now there are no notifications asking the user to update. If you use an ISO and update it, it will go through as expected.

Comment: I have backup of all the pdf files but I cannot backup the places  that are layered across my C: drive...How much space provides Google Drive and how do I access it?

Comment: Will it be better/wiser to still wait for an even higher version of Win than are Win 10?

Comment: @singhnsk I read a few articles that says it has ceased within the last month, but some said it still does work if you have a valid Windows 7/8/8.1 installation. Have you used the upgrade process recently? I would say it's worth a shot.

Comment: If you're waiting for a successor to Windows 10, you might wait some time, Windows 10 is a good choice and you can upgrade in some cases for free.

Comment: @DrZoo Not recently. So, I'll try it on Sunday and let's see how it goes.

Comment: @user2925716 I would upgrade to Windows 10. It will be a while before the next Windows OS is released.

Comment: But I can live with 8.1 up to the year 2023 when all the support will be stopped. By then there should be a new version of Windows shouldn't it?

Comment: That might be the case, but don't forget that Windows was an operating system designed for desktops, insiders are claiming that Microsoft is monitoring the market to see where things are going since handheld are the most used computers and Windows is barely present there in order to make its next move, they did not become who they are by rushing things.